# How to render a <section> tag in JSF 2.2?

Tags: html, jsf-2.2

I have a HTML5 page which I need to convert to a JSF (XHTML) page due to project requirement. In the HTML5 page I have a section tag, I am unable to find a matching component in JSF 2.2 for it. I am using Prime face 6.0 for JSF implementation.

```
<section style="background-image: url('/resources/images/mbr-1-1620x1080.jpg');"  class="header3 headerStyle fullscreen background" id="header3">
```

What should be the JSF component to replace this?

If there is none then which JSF component can I use to have a background image while other component like text field, etc can display on top of that background image. I tried using div background image, it doesn't work. h:graphicImage makes it sequential not background effect. :(

Comment: It's certainly possible, but the right approach depends on the exact functional requirement for which you thought that turning the plain HTML element into a JSF component would be the correct solution. It's still not clear to us why exactly you want to make it a JSF component. It sounds too much like an arbitrary decision instead of a real technical decision.

Comment: The need was to support a dynamic web application user interface and most of the developers were comfortable with JSF. Also the business need was a responsive UI, the UI team that was engaged for initial period of the project provided the HTML pages using bootstrap and HTML5 tags.

Comment: You can put a section tag in an XHTML document. It just needs to be properly closed (i.e. `<section></section>`, `<section />`). Why make it difficult? Boostrap can work with JSF. You can also use img instead of h:graphicImage.